# Не работают подсказки в JETBrains Rider

Tags: c#, unity3d, rider

Установил Rider для работы с Unity, везде установил галочки при установке. Но при написании кода нет никаких подсказок, не показывается структуру кода. Возможно нужна какая-то настройка? Допустим при написании `Debug.Log();` мне не показало методы класса Debug, в том числе и метод Log. Такая же проблема и со стандартными классами C# например с Console.WriteLine(using System писал)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Настроил конфигурацию и попробовал запустить дебаг и все заработало

Comment: В Unity нужно выбрать редактор кода: Edit->Preferences->External Tools->Rider. После чего будет генерироваться файл решения